# How do I move multiple identical rectangles in a list separately?

Tags: python, pygame, 2d-games

I'm trying to spawn an infinite amount of enemies at a given rate, and have them move towards the player. However, I can only manage to get two to spawn, one for each original rectangle where they spawn. This is because the movement overwrites the rectangle they spawn with, so any further enemies simply spawn on top of one of the first two. This is using the move_ip() function, which i think may be the problem, but attempting to just use move() results in no movement at all.

```
def main():
global DISPLAYSURF, FPSCLOCK

pygame.init()
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH,WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption ('Ronin')
checkForQuit()

enemies = []
playerX = 730



enemyImage = pygame.image.load('enemyidle.png')
enemySurf = pygame.transform.scale(enemyImage, (PLAYERWIDTH, PLAYERHEIGHT))
leftRect = pygame.Rect(0, 735, PLAYERWIDTH, PLAYERHEIGHT)
rightRect = pygame.Rect(1500, 735, PLAYERWIDTH, PLAYERHEIGHT)
moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = False
enemycounter = 0

while True:

    checkForQuit()




    #Draw the background
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(backgroundSurf, backgroundRect)

    #draw the player
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(playerSurf, playerRect)


    #time the enemy spawn and draw the enemies


    enemy = random.choice([leftRect, rightRect])

    if enemycounter < ENEMYSPAWNRATE:
            enemycounter += 1
    if enemycounter == ENEMYSPAWNRATE:
            enemycounter = 0
            enemies.append(enemy)

    enemyAI(enemies, playerRect)

    for e in enemies:
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(enemySurf, e)



    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)






def enemyAI(enemies, playerRect):
    for e in enemies:
        if e.left > playerRect.right:
            e.move_ip(-1 * PLAYERSPEED +5, 0)
        if e.right < playerRect.left:
            e.move_ip(PLAYERSPEED -5, 0)



main()
```

I can see in the debugger that each new enemy added to the enemies list has the same coordinates as one of the first two existing enemies. But I want them to appear at the original coordinates specified by either leftRect or rightRect.

Answer (score 0):

You are mostly correct. Your problem lies in creating two rectangles, and then assigning each enemy to one of those two rectangles.

Because the `enemy = random.choice(...)` creates an alias for either `leftRect` or `rightRect`, and because you `enemies.append(enemy)`, you have a list that consists of aliases to the same two rectangles.

Try making a `.copy()` of the rectangle after you randomly choose it:

```
startLocations = (leftRect, rightRect)

def new_enemy():
    """Return a new enemy rect randomly in one of the start locations"""
    return random.choice(startLocations).copy()

while True:

    # ... as before ...

    #time the enemy spawn and draw the enemies
    if enemycounter < ENEMYSPAWNRATE:
        enemycounter += 1
    else:
        enemycounter = 0
        enemies.append(new_enemy())

    enemyAI(enemies, playerRect)

    # ... as before ...
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I was able to just add .copy() to the end of enemy = random.choice(leftRect, rightRect).